When to add a random effect in a GAM model?
So I have a dataset on plant-bird interactions on a particular shrub species across an elevational gradient. We observed 40 shrubs at four elevational bands, during two consecutive days.  With this observations we modelled the frequency of visitation (visits/h) across the elevational gradient on this shrub. I used GAMM models for this purpose. I have included shrub ID as a random factor in my model, to account for the variability due to the individual differences of each shrub. Is this approach okay? The shrubs were observed only once.
Should I run again without the random factor for shrub ID? For running the models I have used gamm function from the R package mgcv.
